# Advanced Custom Fields deleting some code and adding code for a slider

Tags: custom-field, html

Can someone help me? I am not familiar with Custom Fields but I am gaining an understanding of how it works.

I currently have a website that has been built using Advanced Custom Fields. I can see an element that shows on every page (some writing and 5 images) I have located in the `HTML` where this element sits and can remove it but want to replace with a slider.

Do I simply add the code for the slider within this `HTML` for it to show in the same place on the front end and without having to create a new Custom Field?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but as I understand you want to place ACF field on your pages. You can edit custom field in Custom Fields, choose desired field group and custom field and simply edit it.

If you want to create new field and place it on your page just use this in function.php

```
function function_name( $atts ){
    $picture_name = get_field( 'field_name' );
return $function_name;
}
add_shortcode( 'your_field', 'function_name' );
```

And place shortcode [your_field] on page. Or use it directly in template with `<?php echo get_field( 'field_name' ); ?>`